# How to solve Incorrect syntax near '10' error

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2

```
using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(
    "select TaskTimeIn, TaskTimeOut, TaskDescription
     from DailyTimeSheetTrackers
     where EmployeeId = "+UserLog.UserId+" and CreateDateTime = " + DateTime.Now + ""
    )
)
```

Error:

> Incorrect syntax near '10'.

I got error like this.

How to solve it? Please help me

Comment: What language are you using?  I'm guessing C# but I could be off.

Comment: [SQL Injection alert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) - you should **not** concatenate together your SQL statements - use **parametrized queries** instead to avoid SQL injection. That will most likely also remove the error you have (which is due to missing single quotes around your data that you're concatenating into your SQL statement)

Comment: Dates and strings need to be put between single quotes in SQL strings, if you manually construct the SQL string. But as marc_s correctly points out, you are better of using parametrized queries to avoid sql injection.